# SDDM Numlock Non Functional

Tags: kubuntu, 23.04, sddm

Having an issue in kubuntu 23.04 where even if i check the 'nublock on' box for boot, it does not apply the setting. Also, to get numlock to turn on, it must be pressed two times. I have confirmed this on a laptop as well as a desktop, both have the same issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you don't get a solid answer, you can try [numlockx](https://linux-tips.us/how-to-tell-if-you-are-you-using-uefi-or-bios/) which should work regardless of your display manager.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will look into that, I thought numlockx didn't start until after login.